# 401 or 404, when trying to authorize a user

Tags: api, http

I have this argument with a co-worker while trying to authenticate a user with login API, what status code is best returned, 404 or 401, in a scenario the user doesn't exist, which still means the user is not authorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing a `GET` request on resource with a uri that identifies the user? `404` makes sense for this.

Are you doing a `POST` request on some `/login` endpoint, and the user doesn't exist? `401` might make more sense for this, `409` or `400` too, but I don't think `404` makes sense to me.

If it's a `POST` request to something called `/login`, and I *do* get a 404, this suggests to me that I have the endpoint wrong, it doesn't suggest to me that the information in the request body was wrong.